# How generate dynamic arns in cloudformation

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I have a parameter in cloudformation like this.

```
Parameters:
  Names:
    Default: "name1,name2,name3"
    Type: CommaDelimitedList
```

Now i want to generate arns from this list for iam resource

```
Resources:
  - "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:lambda/name1"
  - "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:lambda/name2"
  - "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:lambda/name3"
```

Comment: Did you investigate using [Fn::ForEach](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-foreach.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `!Select` function to select a specific value from the `CommaDelimitedList`  parameter in conjunction with the `!Sub` function to construct the ARN.

```
        Resource:
          - !Sub 
            - 'arn:aws:iam::111111111111:lambda/${var}'
            - var: !Select [0, !Ref Names]
          - !Sub 
            - 'arn:aws:iam::111111111111:lambda/${var}'
            - var: !Select [1, !Ref Names]
          - !Sub 
            - 'arn:aws:iam::111111111111:lambda/${var}'
            - var: !Select [2, !Ref Names]
```